# AlertDialog keeps closing on PositiveButton click

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I am having a Alert Dialog popping when i press a certain button from my last 
     layout. There are 3 Text fields that i need to enter before i save the 
      data.the code should work like this: if one text field is empty, Toast 
      pops up and  gives the information that text field is empty and that  it should be filled up with data. It should also set focus on that text field that is empty. Now, the problem is , when i click on positiveButton and try to save my data (even my text field is empty), alert dialog closes and there is only Toast that gives a warning that text field is empty and alert dialog is removed. I am providing a code that makes alert dialog and i will try to provide more  info if someone can understand me and help me :D

```
final View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(dezurniTelefon_Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.tiket_layout, null);

final EditText EtUzrokProb = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewTiket1);
final EditText EtResenjeProb = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewTiket2);
final EditText EtVremeTrajanja = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.textViewTiket3);

final AlertDialog d1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(dezurniTelefon_Activity.this)
     .setTitle("Tiket: " + IdTiketa   )
     .setPositiveButton("Sačuvaj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
     {

        String stringUzrok = EtUzrokProb.getText().toString();
        String stringResenje = EtResenjeProb.getText().toString();
        String stringVremeTrajanja = EtVremeTrajanja.getText().toString();
        if (stringUzrok.matches("")  )
            {
             // Toast.makeText(dezurniTelefon_Activity.this, "Unesite uzrok problema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        //EtUzrokProb.requestFocus();
                                                        //  return;

                                                    }
        if (stringResenje.matches("") )                                                        
           {  
              Toast.makeText(dezurniTelefon_Activity.this, "Unesite resenje problema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        if (stringVremeTrajanja.matches("") )
        {                                                      
           Toast.makeText(dezurniTelefon_Activity.this, "Unesite vreme trajanja intervencije", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
          }
       }).setView(view1)
       .setMessage("Firma: " +strNazFir + "\n" + "Vreme: " + vrmStrt)
       .setNegativeButton("Izađi", null)
       .setCancelable(false)
        .show();

                                }


   }).setNegativeButton("Izlaz", null)
     .setNeutralButton("Pozovi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + strBrojTel);
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                        }

                    }).show();
```

Comment: this is an expected alert dialog behaviour . you need to create custom dialog or custom alert dialog for your use case

Comment: Create a custom dialog box  for your case i have given code for it below

Answer (score 3):

> When the user touches any of the action buttons created with an
>   AlertDialog.Builder, the system dismisses the dialog for you.

As it is written in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Create you custom dialog.As mentioned in documentation this is the default dialog behavior. Try below written code.

```
public void popUpWindow() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, 
        android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        Button okBt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_bt);
        Button cancelBt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_bt);

        okBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              // do your validation here
              dialog.dismiss();// dismiss your dialog after doing stuff
            }
        });

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog.dismiss();// dismiss your dialog

            }
        });


}
```